# How to circumvent "Too many open files" in debian

Tags: debian, files, limit, file-descriptors, ulimit

If I want to see all relevant log files of my apache2 server at once, I use

```
tail -f /var/kunden/logs/*log /var/kunden/logs/*log /var/log/apache2/*log |grep -v robots|grep -v favicon
```

But since those are too many files by now, I would like to encrease that limit.

How can I increase it for one ssh session? And How could I increase it globally systemwide?

I can see the open files limit is 1024 on my machine:

```
ulimit -n
1024
```

Comment: Exceeding the file limit is often a sign of a problem.  As already noted, you may have a problem with log rotation.  (Rotated log may drop off your command.)  Outside /var/log/apache2 there shouldn't be many (any) logs related to your Apache server.  Based on your grep pattern, you likely want to restrict your access to access logs.

Comment: thanks for the hint, but my logrotaion works fine. I have so many logs, cause all 1025 domains on my server have their own log file ;)

Comment: Your patterns look like they will also pick up error logs as well as access logs.  This should be a minor issue if you have a single error log.  If you leave this running in a shell, you may want to use `-F` instead of `-f` so logs get reopened when rotated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is Important to know that there are two kinds of limits:

- A **hard limit** is configurable by root only. This is the highest possible value (limit) for the soft limit.
- A **soft limit** can be set by an ordinary user. This is the actual limit in effect.

### Solution for a single session

In the shell set the soft limit:

```
ulimit -Sn 2048
```

This example will raise the actual limit to 2048 but the command will succeed only if the hard limit (check: `ulimit -Hn`) is the same or higher. If you need higher values, raise the hard limit using one of the methods below. The limits are set per process and they are inherited by newly spawned processes, so anything you run after this command in the same shell will have the new limits.

**Changing hard limit in a single session**

This is not easy because only root can change a hard limit and after switching to root you have to switch back to the original user. Here is the solution with `sudo`:

```
sudo sh -c "ulimit -Hn 9000 ; exec su \"$USER\""
```

### System-wide solution

In Debian and many other systems using `pam_limits` you can set the system-wide limits in `/etc/security/limits.conf` and in files in `/etc/security/limits.d`. The conf file contains description. Example lines:

```
@webadmins       hard     nofile     16384
@webadmins       soft     nofile      8192
```

This will set the hard limit and default soft limit for users in group `webadmins` after login.

### Other limits

The hard limit value is limited by global limit of open file descriptors value in `/proc/sys/fs/file-max` which is pretty high by default in modern Linux distributions. This value is limited by `NR_OPEN` value used during kernel compilation.

### Is there not a better solution?

Maybe you could check if all the `*log` files you feed to `tail -f` are really active files which need to be monitored. It is possible that some of them are already closed for logging and you can just open a smaller number of files.

Comment: ulimit -Sn 4096
-bash: ulimit: open files: Kann die Grenze nicht ändern: Das Argument ist ungültig -- means the argument is not valid

Comment: @rubo77: I added information about the hard limit which is most probably the cause of the problem.

Comment: @rubo77: It is also possible to set the hard limit in a shell session but is it tricky as you have to `su` to root and `su` back to the user: `su -c "ulimit -Hn 6000 ; su $USER"`

Comment: OK, so for a temporary change of the limit I will use `ulimit -Hn 6000; ulimit -Sn 6000` as root then

Comment: since `man ulimit` doesent provide any help, this man page might be of interest: http://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html

Comment: @rubo77: **Regarding the temporary switching:** Since changing hard limits require root privileges I would recommend you raising the hard limit system-wide for users which need it in `/etc/security/limits...` otherwise you have to complicatedly switch to root and back which increases risk of doing mistakes under the root account. **Regarding the man page:** `ulimit` is a shell built-in command (like `cd`) so it is described in the man page of the shell. Alternatively in `bash` you can type `help ulimit`. `man ulimit` will probably show you C library call `ulimit()` from the man section 3.

Comment: how do the values in `/etc` take effect? Do i need to restart something?

Comment: @amenthes I guess you mean the configuration files in `/etc/limits.*`. These limits are applied whenever the PAM module `pam_limits.so` is called. Normally it is at start of a session. For example in Ubuntu 14.04 it is in these tools / commands: `cron`, `login` (text console login), `lightdm` (the GUI login), `su`. You can set where is [`pam_limits`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_limits) used in `/etc/pam.*`. See for example: http://www.faqs.org/docs/securing/chap5sec44.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the PHP Warning in my Apache error.log:

```
failed to open stream: Too many open files in ...
```

So I found out, apache sets this value individually while starting (on my Ubuntu 14.04). It is configured in `/etc/apache2/envvars`. It says:

```
## If you need a higher file descriptor limit, uncomment and adjust the
## following line (default is 8192):
#APACHE_ULIMIT_MAX_FILES='ulimit -n 65536'
```

so I had to adjust the third line.