# How do I loop through only directories in bash?

Tags: bash, files, directory

I have a folder with some directories and some files (some are hidden, beginning with dot).

```
for d in *; do
 echo $d
done
```

will loop through all files and directories, but I want to loop only through directories. How do I do that?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you need to select more specific files than only directories use `find` and pass it to `while read`:

```
shopt -s dotglob
find * -prune -type d | while IFS= read -r d; do 
    echo "$d"
done
```

Use `shopt -u dotglob` to exclude hidden directories (or `setopt dotglob`/`unsetopt dotglob` in zsh).

`IFS=` to avoid splitting filenames containing one of the `$IFS`, for example: `'a b'`

see [AsymLabs answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/96912/20661) below for more `find` options

---

edit:
In case you need to create an exit value from within the while loop, you can circumvent the extra subshell by this trick:

```
while IFS= read -r d; do 
    if [ "$d" == "something" ]; then exit 1; fi
done < <(find * -prune -type d)
```

Comment: I found this solution on: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8489394/1069083

Comment: [Don't loop over the output of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697). It doesn't matter that you set `IFS` to an empty string, it will still break on filenames containing newlines.  It doesn't matter that these filenames are rare, if it's easy to write code that copes with _all_ filenames, then there's no reason to write code that doesn't.

Comment: @Kusalananda "Don't loop over the output of `find`" is misleading. It is fine, provided that output elements are not line-terminated (the default), rather null-terminated. This would require changing the IFS to the 0-byte OR making `read` handle it with `read -d`. Then even filenames containing newlines would be processed correctly.

Comment: @JonathanKomar It is not misleading as none of the precautions are taken in this answer. Changing `IFS` to contain a nul character implies a shell that can store these in variables. The `bash` shell does not do that. `read -d` is `bash`-specific (`xargs -0` would be a better fit as it isn't dependent on the shell, even though it's still not standard). My point is that if you can do it right, in a way that is portable and safe, then there is no reason to make it unportable and/or unsafe. `find` has `-exec` for the very reason to provide a way to iterate over found pathnames with user code!

Comment: @kusalananda: please provide a separate answer with your solution, so we can upvote it

Comment: @rubo77 I did, just now.

Answer (score 711):

You can specify a slash at the end to match only directories:

```
for d in */ ; do
    echo "$d"
done
```

If you want to exclude symlinks, use a test to `continue` the loop if the current entry is a link. You need to remove the trailing slash from the name in order for `-L` to be able to recognise it as a symbolic link:

```
for d in */ ; do
    [ -L "${d%/}" ] && continue
    echo "$d"
done
```

Comment: You can loop through hidden files too with `for d in */ .*/ : do ...`. But how do I loop through hidden files excluding `../`?

Comment: to use only the physical system (not symlinks), another option is 'set -P'

Comment: @AsymLabs That's incorrect, `set -P` only affects commands which change directory. http://sprunge.us/TNac

Comment: If you want this to be recursive you can use `**/`

Comment: Can someone explain the `*/ ;` a little more?  I am having trouble understanding exactly that the code is/does.

Comment: @timbram: `*` is a wildcard, it stands for "anything". `/` means the "anything" must be a directory in order to match the wildcard expression. `;` is part of the for loop, it separates the `do` from the `for`.

Comment: Add `shopt -s nullglob` to prevent problems if there is no directory in the current folder

Comment: For those curious, this answer prints the directory's _relative_ name (eg `dir1`), not the full directory path (eg `/home/user/dir1`)

Answer (score 136):

You can test with `-d`:

```bash
for f in *; do
    if [ -d "$f" ]; then
        # $f is a directory
    fi
done
```

This is one of the [file test operators](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html).

Comment: Note that it will include symlinks to directories.

Comment: `if [[ -d "$f" && ! -L "$f" ]]` will exclude symlinks

Comment: Will break on empty directory. `if [[ "$f" = "*" ]]; then continue; fi`

Comment: @Piskvorleftthebuilding If the current directory is empty, the `-d` test will be false, so no worries and you don't have to compare against the pattern.

Answer (score 74):

Beware that choroba's solution, though elegant, can elicit unexpected behavior if no directories are available within the current directory. In this state, rather than skipping the `for` loop, bash will run the loop exactly once where `d` is equal to `*/`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for d in */; do
    # Will print */ if no directories are available
    echo "$d"
done
```

I recommend using the following to protect against this case:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for f in *; do
    if [ -d "$f" ]; then
        # Will not run if no directories are available
        echo "$f"
    fi
done
```

This code will loop through all files in the current directory, check if `f` is a directory, then echo `f` if the condition returns true. If `f` is equal to `*/`, `echo "$f"` will not execute.

Comment: Much easier to `shopt -s nullglob`.

Answer (score 14):

You can use pure bash for that, but it's better to use find:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec echo {} \;
```

(find additionally will include hidden directories)

Comment: Note that it doesn't include symlinks to directories. You can use `shopt -s dotglob` for `bash` to include hidden directories. Yours will also include `.`.  Also note that `-maxdepth` is not a standard option (`-prune` is).

Comment: The `dotglob` option is interesting but `dotglob` only applies to the use of `*`. `find .` will always include hidden directories (and the current dir as well)

Answer (score 9):

This is done to find both visible and hidden directories within the present working directory, excluding the root directory:

to just loop through directories:

```
 find -path './*' -prune -type d
```

to include symlinks in the result:

```
find -L -path './*' -prune -type d
```

to do something to each directory (excluding symlinks):

```
find -path './*' -prune -type d -print0 | xargs -0 <cmds>
```

to exclude hidden directories:

```
find -path './[^.]*' -prune -type d
```

to execute multiple commands on the returned values (a very contrived example):

```
find -path './[^.]*' -prune -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -I '{}' sh -c \
"printf 'first: %-40s' '{}'; printf 'second: %s\n' '{}'"
```

instead of 'sh -c' can also use 'bash -c', etc.

Comment: What happens if the echo '*/' in 'for d in echo */' contains, say, 60,000 directories?

Comment: You will get "Too many files" error but that can be solved: [How to circumvent “Too many open files” in debian](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85457/how-to-circumvent-too-many-open-files-in-debian)

Comment: thank you for the link - what I was alluding to is that it is better to avoid this problem.

Comment: -L without ` -maxdepth 1
` option gives me an error on **all** symlinks: `"filename" Too many levels of symbolic links`

Comment: +1 for xargs (build and execute command lines from standard input)

Comment: The xargs example only would works for a subset of directory names 9e.g. those with spaces or newlines would not work). Better to use `... -print0 | xargs -0 ...` if you don't know what the exact names are.

Comment: How do I exclude the directory `.` from the result?

Comment: @rubo77 if you don't have any directories under the current directory with names that start with a dot you can do `find * ....`

Comment: OK, so I edited your answer (that is a must, if you want to do something to all dirs in a folder)

Comment: @rubo77 thanks for the edit - tried to revise the whole post based upon yours and Anthons comments, and to make it POSIX friendly.

Comment: **`xargs` can only execute one operation in one command**, so I think you have to create a function and then call that in xargs. can you add en example?

Comment: @rubo77 added way to exclude hidden files/directories and execution of multiple commands - of course this can be done with a script too.

Comment: I added an example in my answer at the bottom, how to do something to each directory using a function with `find * | while read file; do ...`

Comment: If you don't want to over-engineer the problem, you might get away with something as simple as this:

`find -type d`

Answer (score 4):

You can loop through all directories including hidden directories (beginning with a dot) in one line and multiple commands with:

```
for name in */ .*/ ; do printf '%s is a directory\n' "$name"; done
```

If you want to exclude symbolic links:

```
for name in *; do 
  if [ -d "$name" ] && [ ! -L "$name" ]; then
    printf '%s is a directory\n' "$name"
  fi 
done
```

Note: *Using the list `*/ .*/` works in `bash`, but also displays the folders `.` and `..` while in `zsh` it will not show these but throw an error if there is no hidden file in the folder*

---

A cleaner version that will include hidden directories and exclude `../` will be with the `dotglob` shell option in `bash`:

```
shopt -s dotglob nullglob
for name in */ ; do printf '%s is a directory\n' "$name"; done
```

The `nullglob` shell option makes the pattern disappear completely (instead of remaining unexpanded) if no name matches it. (Use the pattern `*(ND/)` in the `zsh` shell; the `/` makes the preceding `*` match only directories, and the `ND` makes it act as if both `nullglob` and `dotglob` were set)

You may unset `dotglob` and `nullglob` with

```
shopt -u dotglob nullglob
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `find` with `-exec` to loop through the directories and call a **function** in the exec option:

```
dosomething () {
  echo "doing something with $1"
}
export -f dosomething
find ./* -prune -type d -exec bash -c 'dosomething "$0"' {} \;
```

Use `shopt -s dotglob` or  `shopt -u dotglob` to include/exclude hidden directories

Comment: The `nullglob` and `dotglob` shell options would unfortunately not make any difference here as the shell is never used for doing globbing.  The `-path './*'` test would be true for all pathnames as all are found under the `.` directory (the default search path with GNU  `find` if no search path is given).

Comment: Thx, I removed the`-path`

Comment: Well, now it would look in a directory called `*` in the current directory (due to the quoting).  Removing the single quotes would make it search each non-hidden name in the current directory.  You probably want just `.` instead.

Comment: Thx, I removed the single quotes. I think now the `dotglob` option would be effective

Answer (score 1):

This will include the complete path in each directory in the list:

```
for i in $(find $PWD -maxdepth 1 -type d); do echo $i; done
```

Comment: breaks when using folders with spaces

Answer (score 1):

This answer is assuming that *all* that needs to be done is to find the sub-directories of some top-level directory.

For an answer specific to `bash` (and to some degree, the `zsh` shell), see the second part of [rubo77's wiki answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/96904/116858), where `dotglob` and `nullglob` is being used to correctly loop over the directories (or symbolic links to directories) in a single directory.

For a portable solution that does not depend on `bash` for doing the actual selection of files, you may use `find` to loop over all directories in some top-level directory like so:

```bsh
topdir=.

find "$topdir" ! -path "$topdir" -prune -type d -exec sh -c '
    for dirpath do
        # user code goes here, using "$dirpath"
        printf "\"%s\" is a directory\n" "$dirpath"
    done' sh {} +
```

The above code assumes that the top directory that we're interested in is the current directory (`.`).  Set `topdir` to some other pathname to use it on another directory.

The `find` utility is asked to ignore pathnames that are identical to the starting search path with `! -path "$topdir"`, and then to prune (not enter) any other pathnames found.  This limits the search to only the directory referenced by `$topdir`.

Pathnames that are directories (`-type d`) are collected and a `sh -c` script is executed with batches of these as arguments.  The `sh -c` script is the code that we'd like to execute on all the directories, so it iterates over its given arguments and does whatever it needs to do with each of them.  If you need to do something that requires `bash`, you would obviously use `bash -c` instead.

The `sh -c` script could be separated out into its own script like so:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

for dirpath do
    # user code goes here, using "$dirpath"
    printf '"%s" is a directory\n' "$dirpath"
done
```

... which would be called from `find` like so:

```bsh
find "$topdir" ! -path "$topdir" -prune -type d -exec ./myscript.sh {} +
```

See also:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)

Comment: You could use `find "$topdir"/*` without `! -path "$topdir"`

Comment: @rubo77 Doing that would make it search all the pathnames matching `"$topdir"/*`.  This pattern would not match hidden names under `$topdir` and would therefore not find any hidden subdirectories in that directory.

Answer (score 1):

Lists only directories. inclusive with spaces in names include hidden directory `-A` if needed:

```bsh
grep '/$' <(ls -AF)
```

Possible sequels:

```bsh
| xargs -I{} echo {}
```

```bsh
| while read; do echo $REPLY; done
```

But judging by the tricky question, it meant the output of directories in the `for` loop and by means of the shell:

```bsh
for i in */ .[^.]*/; do
        [ -h "${i%?}" ] || echo $i
done
```

Comment: Can you explain `[ -h "${i%?}" ]` please?

Comment: `?` - matches any single character. It's similar `${i%/}`. Removes the trailing slash - the directory indicator. Without this, the `-h` and `-L` options in `test` do not work.

Comment: So why don't you use / then? What else would you want to remove at the end?

Comment: This is just one of two equivalent options in this instance because there can only be a slash at the end. This is the first thing that came to my mind.

Answer (score -1):

This lists all the directories together with the number of sub-directories in a given path:

```
for directory in */ ; do D=$(readlink -f "$directory") ; echo $D = $(find "$D" -mindepth 1 -type d | wc -l) ; done
```

Answer (score -3):

```
ls -d */ | while read d
do
        echo $d
done
```

Comment: `This` `is` `one` `directory` `with` `spaces` `in` `the` `name` - but gets parsed as multiple.

Answer (score -6):

```
ls -l | grep ^d
```

or:

```
ll | grep ^d
```

You may set it as an alias

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think this answers the question, which was "I want to loop only through directories" -- which is slightly different than this `ls`-based answer, which *lists* directories.

Comment: It is never a good idea to parse the output of `ls`: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs