# Test for link with trailing slash?

Tags: shell, directory, filenames, symlink, slash

I created in `/tmp/test/`

```
mkdir somedir
ln -s somedir/ somelink
```

I want to [loop through only directories](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86722/how-do-i-loop-through-only-directories-in-bash):

```
for file in */ ; do 
  if [[ -d "$file" && ! -L "$file" ]]; then
    echo "$file is a directory";
  fi;
done
```

but why does this show `somelink is a directory`?

while without the slash it doesent?

```
for file in * ; do 
...
```

And is there a difference in zsh?

Comment: Do you use zsh and/or bash?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trailing slash in the argument given to `-L` causes the symbolic link to always be resolved (i.e. at the level of the lstat(2) call). See POSIX.1 [Base Definitions, General Concepts, Pathname Resolution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_12), or “Trailing slashes” in Linux’s [path_resolution(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/path_resolution).

This is not specific to *zsh*.

You can use a simple [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal) to strip the trailing slash:

```
[[ … -L "${file%/}" … ]]
```

The above should work in any Bourne-like shell (*ksh*, *ash*, *dash*, *bash*, *zsh*, et cetera).