# How can I compress files with the output name same as parent folder?

Tags: tar, compression

How can I compress files with the output name same as parent folder?

For example, I have a the folders:

```
ubup@neter:/NeuroNER-master/output$ tree
.
├── en_2017-04-28_20-26-59-439552
│   ├── 000_test.txt
│   ├── 000_test.txt_conll_evaluation.txt
│   ├── 000_train.txt
│   ├── 000_train.txt_conll_evaluation.txt
│   ├── 000_valid.txt
│   ├── 000_valid.txt_conll_evaluation.txt
│   ├── 001_test.txt
│   ├── 001_test.txt_conll_evaluation.txt
│   ├── 001_train.txt
│   ├── confusion_matrix_for_epoch_0005_in_valid_binary_evaluation.df
│   ├── confusion_matrix_for_epoch_0005_in_valid_bio_evaluation.df
│   ├── confusion_matrix_for_epoch_0005_in_valid_token_evaluation.df
│   ├── model
│   │   ├── checkpoint
│   │   ├── dataset.ickle
│   │   ├── tensorboard_metadata_characters.sv
│   ├── results.son
│   └── tensorboard_logs
│       ├── test
│       │   └── events.ut.fevents.493425627.er
```

I would like to compress the folder `en_2017-04-28_20-26-59-439552` into `en_2017-04-28_20-26-59-439552.tar.bz2`

I could use with the free, open source program  [`lbzip2`](http://lbzip2.org/):

```
tar -c -I lbzip2 -f en_2017-04-28_20-26-59-439552.tar.bz2 *
```

However I don't want the command to contain the name of the archive file (`en_2017-04-28_20-26-59-439552.tar.bz2`), because in my application I don't know it ahead of time.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually used the following bash script:

```
for d in */ ; do
   tar -c -I lbzip2 -f "${d%/}.tar.bz2" "$d"
done
```

Some comments:

- `for d in */ ; do` loop through directories  ([How do I loop through only directories in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86724/16704))
- `${d%/}` removes the trailing slash of the folder name (it would return `$d` unchanged if there was no trailing slash).
- This creates an archive for both subdirectories of the current directories, and symbolic links in the current directory that point to an existing directory.