# What is the proper way to loop through each directory in a for loop?

Tags: bash, directory, for

For example, in this for loop

```
for var in ?????
do
    dummy command
done
```

I would like to be able to loop through each directory in the one that I am currently in, but it will be an unknown list of directories so I can't write every single one into where the question marks are. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I loop through only directories in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86722/how-do-i-loop-through-only-directories-in-bash)

Answer (score 2):

At the very simplest, to satisfy your requirement to "*loop through each directory in the one that i am currently in*", just use a wildcard

```
for d in */
do
    dummy_command "$d"
done
```

If your command can't cope with the trailing slash that's part of `$d`, you can remove it by replacing `"$d"` with `"${d%/}"`.

If your command can take multiple arguments you don't need a loop at all

```
dummy_command */
```

An example of `dummy_command` for testing might be simply `echo`.

**Notice** that in all cases, if there is no match to the `*/` pattern, it will get passed through as a literal asterisk and slash to your command. This is almost certainly not what you want.

For `bash` you can fix it by adding this line above your loop, but be aware it will apply from that point on

```
shopt -s nullglob    # Expand unmatched wildcards to "nothing"
```

...until you have a corresponding `shopt -u nullglob` or your script ends

Answer (score 0):

Like this (list recursively dirs with spaces in file names):

```
shopt -s globstar
dummy_command **/*' '*/
```

or if you insist to use a for loop:

```
shopt -s globstar
for dir in **/*' '*/
    dummy_command "$dir"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want more control over things like min/max depth you can use find in a while loop:

```bsh
while IFS= read -r dir; do
    echo "$dir"
done < <(find . -type d)
```

Then, just change your find options to suit whatever you need.  Like if you are looking for directory names with spaces, you could do `find . -type d -name '* *'`