# for vs find in Bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, performance

When looping through files there are two ways:

1. use a `for`-loop:

   ```
   for f in *; do
       echo "$f"
   done
   ```
2. use `find`:

   ```
   find * -prune | while read f; do 
       echo "$f"
   done
   ```

Assuming these two loops will find the same list of files, what are the differences in those two options in **perfomance** and handling?

Comment: on large amount of files, you might need to [circumvent “Too many open files” in debian](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85457/how-to-circumvent-too-many-open-files-in-debian)

Comment: Why? `find` doesn't open the files it finds. The only thing I can see biting you here with respect to a large number of files is [ARG_MAX](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/).

Comment: See the answers and comments that tell you that `read f` will mangle file names as it reads them (e.g. names with leading blanks).  Also `find * -prune` seems to be a very convoluted way to say simply `ls -1` yes?

Comment: **Don't** assume that the two loops will find the same set of files; in most cases, they won't. Also, that should be `find .`, not `find *`.

Comment: @IDAllen not quite since parsing ls is a [bad idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: @terdon Yes, parsing `ls -l` is a bad idea.  But parsing `ls -1` (that's a `1` not an `l`) is no worse than parsing `find * -prune`.  Both fail on files with newlines in the names.

Comment: @alexis No, `find .` and `find *` do not give the same results with the `-prune` expression.

Comment: in my example `*` is just an example. could be also `find 'something*'`. So we need two things here: **1. handling**: a way to handle all special characters on all different environments. And more interesting: **2. performance**: the differences between for and find using wildcards like * opposing using find with a direct path like "./" (without -prune then)

Comment: `find 'something*'`? You do realize that the argument of `find` gives places to search, not things to search for?

Comment: I suspect that we've each spent more time reading this question and responses than the total difference in performance over the life of the script in question.

Comment: @mpez0 haha, yeah, such is the cost of arbitrary hotness points.

Comment: @rubo77 - perhaps you could mark one these fine A's as the accepted one? I think Stephane's is probably the best but it's entirely up to you. Thanks for taking time to both ask your Q and in reviewing the A's.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1.

The first one:

> ```
> for f in *; do
>   echo "$f"
> done
> ```

fails for files called `-n`, `-e` and variants like `-nene` and with some bash deployments, with filenames containing backslashes.

The second:

> ```
> find * -prune | while read f; do 
>   echo "$f"
> done
> ```

fails for even more cases (files called `!`, `-H`, `-name`, `(`, file names that start or end with blanks or contain newline characters...)

It's the shell that expands `*`, `find` does nothing but print the files it receives as arguments. You could as well have used `printf '%s\n'` instead which as `printf` is builtin would also avoid the *too many args* potential error.

2.

The expansion of `*` is sorted, you can make it a bit faster if you don't need the sorting. In `zsh`:

```
for f (*(oN)) printf '%s\n' $f
```

or simply:

```
printf '%s\n' *(oN)
```

`bash` has no equivalent as far as I can tell, so you'd need to resort to `find`.

3.

```
find . ! -name . -prune ! -name '.*' -print0 |
  while IFS= read -rd '' f; do
    printf '%s\n' "$f"
  done
```

(above using a GNU/BSD `-print0` non-standard extension).

That still involves spawning a find command and use a slow `while read` loop, so it will probably be slower than using the `for` loop unless the list of files is huge.

4.

Also, contrary to shell wildcard expansion, `find` will do a `lstat` system call on each file, so it's unlikely that the non-sorting will compensate for that.

With GNU/BSD `find`, that can be avoided by using their `-maxdepth` extension which will trigger an optimization saving the `lstat`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name '.*' -print0 |
  while IFS= read -rd '' f; do
    printf '%s\n' "$f"
  done
```

Because `find` starts outputting file names as soon as it finds them (except for the stdio output buffering), where it may be faster is if what you do in the loop is time consuming and the list of file names is more than a stdio buffer (4/8 kB). In that case, the processing within the loop will start before `find` has finished finding all the files. On GNU and FreeBSD systems, you may use `stdbuf` to cause that to happen sooner (disabling stdio buffering).

5.

The POSIX/standard/portable way to run commands for each file with `find` is to use the `-exec` predicate:

```
find . ! -name . -prune ! -name '.*' -exec some-cmd {} ';'
```

In the case of `echo` though, that's less efficient than doing the looping in the shell as the shell will have a builtin version of `echo` while `find` will need to spawn a new process and execute `/bin/echo` in it for each file.

If you need to run several commands, you can do:

```
find . ! -name . -prune ! -name '.*' -exec cmd1 {} ';' -exec cmd2 {} ';'
```

But beware that `cmd2` is only executed if `cmd1` is successful.

6.

A canonical way to run complex commands for each file is to call a shell with `-exec ... {} +`:

```
find . ! -name . -prune ! -name '.*' -exec sh -c '
  for f do
    cmd1 "$f"
    cmd2 "$f"
  done' sh {} +
```

That time, we're back to being efficient with `echo` since we're using `sh`'s builtin one and the `-exec +` version spawns as few `sh` as possible.

7.

In **my tests on a directory with 200.000 files** with short names on ext4, the `zsh` one (paragraph 2.) is by far the fastest, followed by the first simple `for i in *` loop (though as usual, `bash` is a lot slower than other shells for that).

Comment: what does the `!` do in the find command?

Comment: @rubo77, `!` is for negation. `! -name . -prune more...` will do `-prune` (and `more...` since `-prune` always returns true) for every file but `.`. So it will do `more...` on all the files in `.`, but will exclude `.` and will not descend into subdirectories of `.`. So it's the standard equivalent of GNU's `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1`.

Answer (score 20):

I tried this on a directory with 2259 entries, and used the `time` command.

The output of `time for f in *; do echo "$f"; done` (minus the files!) is:

```
real    0m0.062s
user    0m0.036s
sys     0m0.012s
```

The output of `time find * -prune | while read f; do echo "$f"; done` (minus the files!) is:

```
real    0m0.131s
user    0m0.056s
sys     0m0.060s
```

I ran each command several times, so as to eliminate cache misses.  This suggests keeping it in `bash` (for i in ...) is quicker than using `find` and piping the output (to `bash`)

Just for completeness, I dropped the pipe from `find`, since in your example, it's wholly redundant. The output of of just `find * -prune` is:

```
real    0m0.053s
user    0m0.016s
sys     0m0.024s
```

Also, `time echo *` (output isn't newline separated, alas):

```
real    0m0.009s
user    0m0.008s
sys     0m0.000s
```

At this point, I suspect the reason `echo *` is quicker is it's not outputting so many newlines, so the output isn't scrolling as much.  Let's test...

```
time find * -prune | while read f; do echo "$f"; done > /dev/null
```

yields:

```
real    0m0.109s
user    0m0.076s
sys     0m0.032s
```

while `time find * -prune > /dev/null` yields:

```
real    0m0.027s
user    0m0.008s
sys     0m0.012s
```

and `time for f in *; do echo "$f"; done > /dev/null` yields:

```
real    0m0.040s
user    0m0.036s
sys     0m0.004s
```

and finally: `time echo * > /dev/null` yields:

```
real    0m0.011s
user    0m0.012s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Some of the variation can be accounted for by random factors, but it seems clear:

- output is slow
- piping costs a bit
- `for f in *; do ...` is slower than `find * -prune`, on its own, but for the constructions above involving pipes, is quicker.

Also, as an aside, both approaches appear to handle names with spaces just fine.

EDIT:

Timings for `find . -maxdepth 1 > /dev/null` vs. `find * -prune > /dev/null`:

`time find . -maxdepth 1 > /dev/null`:

```
real    0m0.018s
user    0m0.008s
sys     0m0.008s
```

`find * -prune > /dev/null`:

```
real    0m0.031s
user    0m0.020s
sys     0m0.008s
```

So, additional conclusion:

- `find * -prune` is slower than `find . -maxdepth 1` - in the former, the shell is processing a glob, then building a (large) command line for `find`. NB: `find . -prune` returns just `.`.

More tests:  `time find . -maxdepth 1 -exec echo {} \; >/dev/null`:

```
real    0m3.389s
user    0m0.040s
sys     0m0.412s
```

Conclusion:

- slowest way to do it so far.  As was pointed out in the comments for the answer where this approach was suggested, each argument spawns a shell.

Comment: Which pipe is redundant? can you show the line you used without pipe?

Comment: @rubo77 `find * -prune | while read f; do echo "$f"; done` has the redundant pipe - all the pipe is doing is outputting exactly what `find` outputs on its own.  Without a pipe, it would be simply `find * -prune`  The pipe is only redundant specifically because the thing on the other side of the pipe simply copies stdin to stdout (for the most part).  It's an expensive no-op.  If you want to do stuff with the output of find, other than to just spit it back out again, that's different.

Comment: Maybe the main timeconsuming is the `*`. As **BitsOfNix** stated: *I still strongly suggest to not use `*` and `.` for `find` instead.*

Comment: @rubo77 seems that way.  I guess I overlooked that.  I've added findings for my system.   I assume `find . -prune` is faster because `find` will be reading a directory entry verbatim, while the shell will be doing likewise, potentially matching against the glob (might optimize for `*`), then building the large command line for `find`.

Comment: So the first conclusion "for f in ... is slower than find, on its own" should be "`for f in * ...` is slower than `find * -prune`", on its own"

Comment: @rubo77 yes, I agree.  I'll edit.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11156/discussion-between-phil-and-rubo77)

Comment: `find . -prune` prints only `.` on my system.  It does almost no work at all.  It is not at all the same as `find * -prune` that shows all the names in the current directory.  A bare `read f` will mangle file names with leading spaces.

Comment: @Phil: that's correct: `find .` only works without `-prune` otherwise it is just one entry: `./` itself. So Phil, could you please pass the tests with `find .` again without -prune?

Comment: @IDAllen great catch, thanks!  @rubo77 I've rerun the test - `find` is still quicker, but not by quite such a large margin!

Answer (score 10):

I would go definitely with find although I would change your find to just this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -exec echo {} \;
```

Performance wise, `find` is a lot faster depending on your needs of course. What you have currently with `for` it will only display the files/directories in the current directory but not the directories contents. If you use find it will also show the contents of the sub-directories.

I say find is better since with your `for` the `*` will have to be expanded first and I'm afraid that if you have a directory with a huge amount of files it might give the error *argument list too long*. Same goes for `find *`

As an example, in one of the systems that I currently use there is a couple of directories with over 2million files (<100k each):

```
find *
-bash: /usr/bin/find: Argument list too long
```

Comment: I added `-prune` to make the two examples more alike. and I prefer the pipe with while so it is easier to apply more commands in the loop

Comment: You can [circumvent “Too many open files” in debian](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85457/how-to-circumvent-too-many-open-files-in-debian)

Comment: changing the hard limit is hardly a proper workaround from my POV. Specially when talking about 2+ million files. Without digression from the Question, for simple cases as one level directory for is faster, but if you change your file/directory structure it will be harder to migrate. While with find and it's huge amount of options you can be better prepared. Still I still strongly suggest to not use * and . for find instead. It would be more portable than * where you might not be able to control the hardlimit ...

Comment: That will spawn one echo process per file (while in the shell for loop, it's the echo builtin that will be used without forking an extra process), and will descend into directories, so it will be a lot _slower_. Also note that it will include dot files.

Comment: You are right, I added the maxdepth 1 so that it sticks to the current level only.

Comment: @BitsOfNix I tested this option under the same conditions as I have for the others in my answer, and I found it to be exceedingly slow.

Answer (score 7):

```
find * -prune | while read f; do 
    echo "$f"
done
```

is a useless use of `find` - What you're saying is effectively "for each file in the directory (`*`), don't find any files. Also, it's not safe for several reasons:

- Backslashes in paths are treated specially without the `-r` option to `read`. This is not an issue with the `for` loop.
- Newlines in paths would break any non-trivial functionality inside the loop. This is not an issue with the `for` loop.

Handling any file name with `find` is [difficult](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/master/examples/safe-find.sh), so you should use the `for` loop option whenever possible for that reason alone. Also, running an external program like `find` will in general be slower than running an internal loop command like `for`.

Comment: @I0b0 What about find -path './*' -prune or find -path './[^.]*' -prune (to avoid hidden files and directories) as a better construct - in full form: find -path './*' -prune -print0 | xargs -0 sh -c ' ... '?

Comment: Neither `find`'s `-print0` nor `xargs`' `-0` are POSIX compatible, and you can't put arbitrary commands in `sh -c ' ... '` (single quotes cannot be escaped within single quotes), so it's not quite so simple.

Answer (score 4):

But we are suckers for performance questions! This request-for-experiment makes at least two assumptions that make it not terribly valid.

A. Assume that they find the same files…

Well, they *will* find the same files at first, because they're both iterating over the same glob, namely `*`. But `find * -prune | while read f` suffers from several flaws that make it quite possible it won't find all the files you expect:

1. POSIX find isn't guaranteed to accept more than one path argument. Most `find` implementations do, but still, you shouldn't rely on that.
2. `find *` can break when you hit `ARG_MAX`. `for f in *` will not, because `ARG_MAX` applies to `exec`, not builtins.
3. `while read f` can break with filenames starting and ending with whitespace, which will get stripped off. You could overcome this with `while read` and its default parameter `REPLY`, but that still won't help you when it comes to filenames with newlines in them.

B. `echo`. Nobody's going to do this just to echo the name of the file. If you want that, just do one of these:

```
printf '%s\n' *
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 # for dotted names, too
```

The pipe to the `while` loop here creates an implicit subshell that closes when the loop ends, which might be unintuitive for some.

To answer the question, here are the results in a directory of mine that has 184 files and directories in it.

```
$ time bash -c 'for i in {0..1000}; do find * -prune | while read f; do echo "$f"; done >/dev/null; done'

real    0m7.998s
user    0m5.204s
sys 0m2.996s
$ time bash -c 'for i in {0..1000}; do for f in *; do echo "$f"; done >/dev/null; done'

real    0m2.734s
user    0m2.553s
sys 0m0.181s
$ time bash -c 'for i in {0..1000}; do printf '%s\n' * > /dev/null; done'

real    0m1.468s
user    0m1.401s
sys 0m0.067s

$ time bash -c 'for i in {0..1000}; do find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 >/dev/null; done '

real    0m1.946s
user    0m0.847s
sys 0m0.933s
```

Comment: I don't agree with the statement the while loop spawns a subshell - at worst case, a new thread: the following is trying to show before and after, apologies for the poor formatting `$ ps ax | grep bash
20784 pts/1    Ss     0:00 -bash
20811 pts/1    R+     0:00 grep bash
$ while true; do while true; do while true; do while true; do while true; do sleep 100; done; done; done; done; done 
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 sleep 100
$ bg
[1]+ sleep 100 &
$ ps ax | grep bash
20784 pts/1    Ss     0:00 -bash
20924 pts/1    S+     0:00 grep bash`

Comment: Technically I misspoke: the *pipe* causes the implicit subshell, not the while loop. I'll edit.

Answer (score 2):

`find *` will not work right if `*` produces tokens which look like predicates rather than paths.

You cannot use the usual `--` argument to fix this because `--` indicates the end of options, and find's options come before paths.

To fix this issue you can use `find ./*` instead. But then it's not producing exactly the same strings as `for x in *`.

Note that `find ./* -prune | while read f ..` does not actually use the scanning functionality of `find`. It is the globbing syntax `./*` which actually traverses the directory and generates names. Then the `find` program will have to perform at least a `stat` check on each one of those names. You have the overhead of launching the program and having it access these files, and then doing I/O to read its output.

It is hard to imagine how it could be anything but less efficient than `for x in ./* ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Well for starters `for` is a shell keyword, built into Bash, while `find` is a separate executable.

```
$ type -a for
for is a shell keyword

$ type -a find
find is /usr/bin/find
```

The `for` loop will only find the files from the globstar character when it expands, it won't recurse into any directories it finds.

Find on the otherhand will also be given a list expanded by the globstar, but it will recursively find all the files and directories below this expanded list and pipe each one through to the `while` loop.

Both these approach might be considered dangerous in the sense that they don't handle paths or filenames that contain spaces.

That's about all I can think of worth commenting on these 2 approaches.

Comment: I added -prune to the find command, so they are more alike.

Answer (score 0):

If all of the files returned by find can be processed by a single command (obviously not applicable to your echo example above), you can use xargs:

```
find * |xargs some-command
```

Answer (score 0):

For years I've been using this:-

```
find . -name 'filename'|xargs grep 'pattern'|more
```

to look for certain files (e.g. *.txt) that contain a pattern that grep can look for and pipe it into more so that it doesn't scroll off the screen. Sometimes I use the >> pipe to write the results to another file that I can look at later.

Here's a sample of the result:-

```
./Documents/Organ_docos/Rodgerstrio321A/rodgersmylist/2008-August.txt:Message-ID: <A165CE5C-61C5-4794-8651-66F5678ABCBF@usit.net>
./Documents/Organ_docos/Rodgerstrio321A/rodgersmylist/2008-August.txt:In-Reply-To: <A165CE5C-61C5-4794-8651-66F5678ABCBF@usit.net>
./Documents/Organ_docos/Rodgerstrio321A/rodgersmylist/2008-August.txt:  <A165CE5C-61C5-4794-8651-66F5678ABCBF@usit.net>
./Documents/Organ_docos/Rodgerstrio321A/rodgersmylist/2008-August.txt:  <A165CE5C-61C5-4794-8651-66F5678ABCBF@usit.net>
./Documents/Organ_docos/Rodgerstrio321A/rodgersmylist/2008-August.txt:Message-ID: <448E53556A3F442ABC58203D6281923E@hypermax>
./Documents/Organ_docos/Rodgerstrio321A/rodgersmylist/2011-April.txt:URL: http://mylist.net/private/rodgersorganusers/attachments/20110420/3f
```