# Condensing multiple spaces in given linux file name without using sed or tr (bash)

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-formatting

I need to write a function that does the following:
the function receives file names with this format `*.station`

Between the words might be multiple spaces, I want to remove the extra
spaces between the words and leave only one.

For example (1):  `aa__________a____aa _____________ ssd________.station`, needs to be changed to `aa_a_aa_ssd.station`

(2): `aa______________a.station` needs to be written as: `aa_a.station`

(The underscores (`_`) signify spaces in the above.)

Comment: i am not allowed to use tr unfortunately

Comment: Why are you "not allowed" to use `tr`?  Is this homework?

Answer (score 1):

```
shopt -s extglob
file="aa     a       a.station"
echo mv "$file" "${file// +( )/ }"
```

An alternative would be a loop with

```
"${file//  / }"
```

until there are only single spaces left:

```
file="a                      a"

last_run=""
new="$file"
while [ "$last_run" != "$new" ]; do
        last_run="$new"
        new="${last_run//  / }"
done

echo mv "$file" "$new"
```

Or with word splitting:

```
IFS=" "
mv "$file" "$(echo $file)"
```

Comment: can you please explain how do i write that loop? assuming all the *.station files are in the current directory.

Comment: @evgniytayarov see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/162586/117549

Comment: and/or https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/97084/117549

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
file="aa     a       a.station"
read -r -a myarray <<< "$file"
printf  "${myarray[*]}"
```

This reads a string into an array, splitting on the standard IFS characters (space, tab, newline). The entire array, each element, now with single delimiters, is then printed.

You can also leverage `xargs`:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="aa     a       a.station"
newfile=$(echo $file|xargs)
printf  "${newfile}"
```

Comment: Why the effort with `read`? `myarray=($file)` And `IFS` should be set to `space` only.